# Connect to Elastic Search through a JDBC (for Wolfram Language)

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, wolfram-language

Specifically, I'm wondering if you can connect the Wolfram language to Elastic Search. Indication is that you can connect Wolfram to any DB that supports JDBC: https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseReference.html#14146

...but I'm having trouble determining if / how to make that connection. I know you ES can connect to other databases through JDBC, but can you connect and interact with ES through a JDBC connection?

(Of course, you can also go through the HTTP layer, so as a followup: would it be more performant?)

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no JDBC driver for Elasticsearch, thus requiring a custom driver to go from Wolfram language to Elasticsearch.